# Installing CUDA and NVIDIA driver on Kubuntu 22.04 from distribution repositories

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, cuda

I switched from Kubuntu 21.10 to 22.04 and tried to install CUDA and NVIDIA drivers as before:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470 # driver
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit # cuda
```

This worked before. But it doesn't on 22.04.

After installing `nvidia-driver-470` I can call `nvidia-smi` just fine. When calling `nvcc`, `apt` expectedly tells me I should install `nvidia-cuda-toolkit`. However after installing `nvidia-cuda-toolkit`, `nvidia-smi` is gone and `apt` tells me I should install `nvidia-driver-470`. This is an endless cycle.

I checked the web and some people solved the issue by no installing the toolkit from repository but from the NVIDIA download page.

Is there a way of installing both (driver and CUDA) from standard packages without collision?